# Earth Engine Python API reducing image collection (mean , median or mosaic) returns no image

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, reducers

I am trying to compute NDVI of an image collection with 10 images in it. I created an ndvi function and mapped that over the image collection. After that I want reduce the collection to a single image with median reducer. However earth engine returns an image with no values.
When I select the first image from the mapped collection, that loads just fine in QGIS however with any reducer / mosaic it returns nothing

Please suggest how to fix it.

This is my code
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nD-AIZgzEQOs2Vf8G749o87A0RXiIrMj?usp=sharing

```
# imports
!pip install -U earthengine-api --no-deps --quiet
import ee
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()

# Study Area
xMin = 70;
yMin = 33;
xMax = 70.3;
yMax = 33.3;
area = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([[xMin, yMin],[xMax, yMax]])

# Filtering an image Collection
s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR").filterBounds(area).filterDate('2022-05-01','2022-05-25')
print(s2.getInfo())
print(s2.first().bandNames().getInfo())

# mapping over image collection
def getNDVI(image):
    # Normalized difference vegetation index (NDVI)
    ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']).rename("ndvi")
    return(ndvi.copyProperties(image,['system:time_start','system:time_end']))
mapped = s2.map(getNDVI)
print(mapped.size().getInfo())

# Reducing to median image
median = mapped.median().clip(area)
print(median.getInfo())

#downloading the tiff
dl = median.getDownloadURL()
print(dl)
```

This is how the first NDVI image appears from the mapped collection
[image: First image from the NDVI collection]

Median image with no values
[image: Median Image With No Values]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the `getDownloadURL()` params and specify the scale you want to export your imagery to. For more details, look [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-getdownloadurl).

```
dl = median.getDownloadURL({'scale': 300})
```

Comment: Thank you once again Daniel... Actually I am new to GEE Python API so needed that. It worked. I think max limit for getDownloadURL is 32 MB can I increase that limit?

Comment: I don't believe you can, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Maybe Noel's article on downloads can be useful: https://gorelick.medium.com/fast-er-downloads-a2abd512aa26